# XML serialization error on XBOX 360

Tags: xna-4.0, xml

When try to save game on an xbox with xml serialization i get a code 4 error. I made sure t oadd all the xml referances and there is no errors until i run the game. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Did you reference the correct xbox360 xml serialization namespace found in

**C:\Program Files\Microsoft XNA\XNA Game Studio\v4.0\References\Xbox360\System.Xml.Serialization.dll** ??

Code 4 is a generic error that is difficult to solve without more information on the xml serialization code you have. Paste it here if you need more help.